# Weird PR2 Image Generation on all cameras

Tags: ros, gazebo, kinect, pr2, images

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I attached an image that I was getting from rviz of the PR2 looking at a bookshelf using the /head_mount_kinect/rgb/image_raw topic.  As you can see, the kinect's RGB image is giving some pink blobs over it.  Does anyone know what these pink blobs are?  They don't seem to be any depth data or anything else.

[image: image description]

By the way, I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with the latest ROS.

Also, I can't use any feature detector such as SIFT, SURF, GFT, etc. on these images or any camera that I'm bringing up from Gazebo.  I don't know if it is a problem with Gazebo or with ROS.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56530/weird-pr2-image-generation-on-all-cameras/) by [astaranowicz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4294/astaranowicz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 238 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [astaranowicz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4294/astaranowicz/) on 2013-02-27**:
I found the answer. Its due to the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the answer. Its due to a texture projector on the PR2. It has to be turned off for any of the image to be useful.  Found here: http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_camera_synchronizer

---

Originally posted by [astaranowicz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4294/astaranowicz/) with karma: 238 on 2013-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0